# how to make fit in dompdf laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6, dompdf

I have problem. If I download a PDF file using dompdf, the result will like this [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qW0TZ.png).

However, what I want is like this: [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocoaN.png).

How can I fix this in my Laravel instance?

This is for my controller...

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('content.Export.ExGeneralInspection')
    ->setPaper('a4', 'portrait');

return $pdf->download('GI.pdf');
```

This for my HTML view...

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http - equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title> Export PDF </title>
</head>
<body class="OnePageImage">

<h2><b> General Inspection </b></h2>
<br>

<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="2" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle"> No .</th>
        <th rowspan="2" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle"> No . Registrasi</th>
        <th rowspan="2" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle"> Judul Temuan</th>
        <th rowspan="2" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle"> Tanggal Temuan</th>
        <th rowspan="2" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle"> Lokasi</th>
        <th rowspan="2" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle"> Auditor</th>
        <th rowspan="2" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle"> Target Selesai</th>
        <th colspan="2" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle"> Auditee</th>
        <th rowspan="2" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle"> Images</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle"> PIC</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle"> Tanggal Tindakan</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    </tbody >
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: used landscape page `$pdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');` . because your table width not fit in `portrait` format

Comment: so, no options to use portrait ?

Answer (score 0):

Please update your HTML. You didn't start tbody you have close tag. So there are some

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http - equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title> Export PDF </title>
</head>
<body class="OnePageImage">

<h2><b> General Inspection </b></h2>
<br>

 <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http - equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title> Export PDF </title>
</head>
<body class="OnePageImage">

<h2><b> General Inspection </b></h2>
<br>

<table style="width:100%">

    <tr>
        <th rowspan="2" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle"> No .</th>
        <th rowspan="2" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle"> No . Registrasi</th>
        <th rowspan="2" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle"> Judul Temuan</th>
        <th rowspan="2" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle"> Tanggal Temuan</th>
        <th rowspan="2" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle"> Lokasi</th>
        <th rowspan="2" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle"> Auditor</th>
        <th rowspan="2" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle"> Target Selesai</th>
        <th colspan="2" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle"> Auditee</th>
        <th rowspan="2" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle"> Images</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle"> PIC</td>
        <td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle"> Tanggal Tindakan</td>
    </tr>


</table>
</body>
</html>
```